# Sitecore 8 is it possible to have multiple/dynamic fields in one template

Tags: sitecore-client

I am developing a dynamic calendar application within a Sitecore instance, and the User case would be..

1. Creation of Event (from and Event Template),
2. Choose multiple dates, and multiple sessions on that date from within the creation of that Event item.

My question is simply...
  Using an Event Template, is it even possible to create multiple and even dynamic fields for the Content Author to choose from ?

(I am mostly looking to learn if Sitecore has the capacity and if so how)

Comment: In the use cases you described, what UI do you want your content authors to use? Will they add events, dates and sessions from the Content Editor or from the Experience Editor?

Comment: Yes, in the best case scenario, the Content Author will be able to add an Event item within the Content Tree and then add Dates and sessions within those dates (Could be from Experience Editor or Content Editor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Sitecore, the best fit for your requirements would be to use item hierarchies.

1. Define 3 data templates: Event, Event Date and Event Session.
2. Restrict what can be inserted under items of each template. Under an Event, you'd only want to insert Event Date items. Under an Even Date, only Event Session items. This can be restricted using Insert Options on each template's Standard Values.
3. The Event rendering you'll create should take an Event item as its data source. You'll be able to traverse the item hierarchy and display the event, it's dates, and all sessions. You can also make all of their fields editable in the Experience Editor.

As a result, content authors will be able to create events with multiple dates, with multiple sessions in each date.

Comment: Thank you, I had figured this might be best way, thanks for confirming